# How to use gmail POP and IMAP from multiple clients simultaneously?

Tags: gmail, imap, ipad, pop3

I use gmail POP with Mail.app on a Mac. It works well for me, and with seven years of emails in it I don't want to change. It's my main place for email and a backup of gmail as well.

I've now got an iPad. I'd like to enable IMAP on gmail so I can use the tablet's mail program as well when I'm out and about. I don't want to use recent mode with POP on both; it looks like a kludge and I can see it going wrong on the Mac client.

Can I re-enable IMAP on my gmail account and use the iPad while keeping POP for the Mac? I don't ever want anything I do on the iPad to affect what's stored in the Mail.app folders on the Mac (other than sending new mail) - it's critically important that the Mac's store stays pristine.

I don't use folders nor do I use the gmail website. I just have one gigantic inbox and I use Spotlight for searching on the Mac. I'm fine with 30 days of email in the iPad; whatever it'll give me. I don't need all seven years.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can use POP and IMAP simultaneously.